# change ip address for docker

Tags: linux, docker

I have a problem with docker: I try to create a container but when I execute

```
docker run -i -t base /bin/bash   # everything doing good 
aptitude update
```

I'm getting this error message:

> Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

I try to change the IP address of `docker0` but all time I fail.

The IP address on my linux

```
 docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/ether 7a:3c:fa:08:73:94 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.42.1
```

My resolv.conf:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 213.244.0.15
nameserver 213.244.0.16
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Are you able to access any ip address outside of your container? There appears to be a networking issue in docker. See: https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/1026

Answer (score 7):

from https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/866#issuecomment-19218300:

You could try to reset all the networking/iptables:

```
pkill docker
iptables -t nat -F
ifconfig docker0 down
brctl delbr docker0
docker -d
```

It will force docker to recreate the bridge and reinit all the network rules.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw that my docker0 interface was down, i executed `sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart`, it went back up and my docker work again.